# Split lists with uncertain elements into different categories (using pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble with a pandas split. So I have a column of data that looks something like this:

**Initial Dataframe**

```
index | Address
0     | [123 New York St]
1     | [Amazing Building, 23 New Jersey St, 2F]
2     | [98 New Mexico Ave, 16F]
3     | [White House, 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, PH]
4     | [221 Baker Street]
5     | [Hogwarts]
```

As you can see, the list contains varying categories and number of elements.  Some have building names along with addresses. Some only have addresses with building floors. I want to sort them out by category (building name, address, unit/floor number) but I'm having trouble coming up with a solution to this, as I'm a beginner python & pandas learner.

**How do I split the addresses into different categories to get an output that looks like this, assuming the building names ALL start with an alphabet and I can put Null for categories with missing value?**

**Desired Output:**

```
index | Building Name    | Address               | Unit Number
0     | Null             | 123 New York St       | Null
1     | Amazing Building | 23 New Jersery St.    | 2F
2     | Null             | 98 New Mexico Ave.    | 16F
3     | White House      | 1600 Pennsylvania Ave | PH
4     | Null             | 221B Baker St         | Null
5     | Hogwarts         | Null                  | Null
```

The main thing I need is for all addresses to be in the Address Column.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where are values 23, 98 coming from? Also, i think converting `TwoTwoOneB` to 221B would not be easy.

Comment: Are the strings always in the format `address` or `building name, address` ? If there isn’t a simple format, then this becomes much more complicated.

Comment: @moys Sorry, I fixed the initial dataframe data. It should be 221B in both now.

Comment: @AMC A list might start with the building name, or it might not. It might just start with an address like index[0]. Let's assume the building name always starts with a alphabet, do you think I should use something like regex to split the elements into their property columns?

Comment: @mrjacklu _A list might start with the building name, or it might not. It might just start with an address like index[0]._ Are those the **only** two options, though? What is the type of the data in the `Address` column, and why use what appears to be `"Null"` ? Please provide a [mcve], including some data in a clear and unambiguous format.

Answer (score 1):

preconditional condition : Building name starts with a character, not a number

If the building name starts with a number, the wrong result can be output.

```
  import pandas as pd

  df = pd.DataFrame({'addr' : ['123 New York St', 
                     'Amzing Building, 23 New Jersey St, 2F',
                     '98 New Mexico Ave, 16F']})
  # Check the number of items in the address value
  df['addr'] = df['addr'].str.split(',')
  df['cnt'] = df['addr'].apply(lambda x: len(x)).values

  # function, Building name start letter check
  def CheckInt(s):
      try:
          int(s[0])
          return True
      except ValueError:
          return False

  for i, v in df.iterrows():
      # One item of address value
      if v.cnt == 1:
          df.loc[i,'Address'] = v.addr
      # Three items of address value
      elif v.cnt == 3:
          df.loc[i,'Building'] = v.addr[0]
          df.loc[i,'Address'] = v.addr[1]
          df.loc[i,'Unit'] = v.addr[2]
      # Two items of address value
      else:
          if CheckInt(v.addr[0]):
              df.loc[i,'Address'] = v.addr[0]
              df.loc[i,'Unit'] = v.addr[1]
          else:
              df.loc[i,'Building'] = v.addr[0]
              df.loc[i,'Address'] = v.addr[1]
```

Comment: Be careful, `iterrows()` is notoriously sluggish, and often times unnecessary and unidiomatic. Also, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the output for your input dataframe as below.
If the data is different, you may have to tinker around.

```
df['com_Address'] = df[' Address'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']','')).str.split(',')
st_list= ['St','Ave']
df['St_Address']=df.apply(lambda x: [a if st in a  else '' for st in st_list for a in x['com_Address']],axis=1)
df['St_Address']=df['St_Address'].apply(lambda x:[i for i in x if i]).astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.strip("[]'"))
df['Building Name']=df.apply(lambda x: [x['com_Address'][0] if len(x['com_Address'])==3 else 'Null'],axis=1).astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.strip("[]'"))
df['Building Name']=df.apply(lambda x: np.where((len(x['com_Address'])==1) & (x['St_Address']==''),x['com_Address'][0],x['Building Name']),axis=1)
df['Unit Number']=df.apply(lambda x: [x['com_Address'][2] if len(x['com_Address'])==3 else 'Null'],axis=1).astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.strip("[]'"))
df['Unit Number']=df.apply(lambda x: np.where((len(x['com_Address'])==2) & (x['St_Address']!=''),x['com_Address'][-1],x['Unit Number']),axis=1)
df
```

Column "com_Address" is optional. I had to create it because the 'Address' from your input came to me as a string & not as a list. If you already have it as list, you don't need this & you will have to update "com_Address" with 'Address' in the code.

**Output**

```
index   Address                                     com_Address                                Building Name    St_Address  Unit Number
0   0   [123 New York St]                           [ 123 New York St]                         Null           123 New York St   Null
1   1   [Amazing Building, 23 New Jersey St, 2F]    [ Amazing Building, 23 New Jersey St, 2F]  Amazing Building     23 New Jersey St    2F
2   2   [98 New Mexico Ave, 16F]                    [ 98 New Mexico Ave, 16F]                  Null     98 New Mexico Ave   16F
3   3   [White House, 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, PH]    [ White House, 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, PH]  White House  1600 Pennsylvania Ave   PH
4   4   [221 Baker Street]                          [ 221 Baker Street]                        Null     221 Baker Street    Null
5   5   [Hogwarts]                                  [ Hogwarts]                                Hogwarts         Null
```

Comment: thank you. I'll test this out to see if it works for the whole dataset.

Comment: Why the `df['com_Address'] = df[' Address'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('[','').replace(']','')).str.split(',')` ?

Comment: @AMC Because when i copy the the table the OP has put, i get it a string & not as a list. I basically converting that to the string with the code. I also mentioned that in my answer.